# open html link inside visitor email manager thunderbird, outlook... rails 3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this link:

```
<div class="email_button">
   <%= link_to "mailto:?subject=#{t('.incredible')}#{@product.title}&body=#{t('.hi')},%0A%0A #{t('.check_it')}#{@canonical_url}", :title => "#{t('.send_email')}", :class => "btn btn-small", :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow" do %>
    <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
    <%= "Email" %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

The html generated:

```
<a title="Send by email" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="btn btn-small" href="mailto:?subject=Incredible. Product title &amp;body=Hi,%0A%0A Take a look: http://www.mydomain.com/es/products/myproduct-1">
    <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
    Email
</a>
```

This code open a new email inside visitor email manager. The `http://www.mydomain.com/es/products/myproduct-1` is not visible like a **html link**. It is visible like a **text link**.

**How can send an html link to visitor email manager instead text link?**

Comment: Maybe the content type, ensure it is sent as html. try to force your mailer with `content_type` option

Comment: Thank you can you specify content type for this question? Thank you!